# Magento 1.9.2 - admin panel 503

Tags: magento, http-status-code-503

I'm having an issue with 503 error. When I'm trying to log into admin panel, i'm getting:

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily busy, try again later!

I'm using LiteSpeed Web Server.

All front pages such as product pages, checkout etc. works fine. 
Admin panel worked fine yesterday and today morning but now it stopped. I haven't changed any files.

If anyone had this problem before and fixed it, or knows could I diagnose it.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: can you try once by deleting var folder.

Comment: whole var folder or just cache?

Comment: if its ok for you, you can delete whole var folder. This will also delete sessions, and other log, reports as well. So you can check freshly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my hosting provider updated PHP to 7.0.7 form 7.0.3 today, and have not informed me about that. That is probably the reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on PHP 7.0.6 & 7.0.7 on Debian Wheezy.
Fallback to PHP 5.6.x or PHP 7.0.3 fix the problem.

On official site, system req. say it should work..
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

If you would strace it, you get something like:

```
[pid  8364] stat("/www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Interface.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2193, ...}) = 0
[pid  8364] lstat("/www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51384, ...}) = 0
[pid  8364] access("/www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php", F_OK) = 0
[pid  8364] stat("/www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51384, ...}) = 0
[pid  8364] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 8364 detached
```

Issues in on Magento 2.0.3, but also on a fresh install on 2.0.7,..